# How do I create a custom 4x4 array using NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am new to Python and I am having a bit of trouble with the array functions.
I want to make a 4 by 4 array which contains the numbers from 1 to 16.

I know that using  `np.zeros((4,4))` outputs a 4x4 array with all zeros.
Using `np.array(range(17))` I can get an array of the required numbers BUT not in the correct shape (4x4).

It must be fairly simple, surely? All comments are much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating an array of 17 values (zero through 16), which can't be reshaped to 4x4. Instead:

```
>>> a = np.arange(1, 17).reshape(4,4)
>>> a
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15, 16]])
```

Comment: Oh I see, I should have noticed that. So is this the standard way of producing custom arrays?

Comment: It depends on how "custom" you want them to be, but it's a very common starting point.  `arange` only gives sequential values (but can start at any number and take steps other than one).  `reshape` works on any array as long as the number of values stack nicely.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by *custom*.  There are numerous ways to create and/or initialize an array. If you just want the shape, you can use `np.empty`, `np.empty_like`, `np.zeros`, etc. If you also want to initialize the values, you can call `np.fromfunction` or others.

Comment: I am assuming that "initialising the values" means to make my own values? What would be the process if I want a n-by-m array with a list of numbers (that fit nicely)? I tried the following and it works nicely:
'a=(1,2,4,66,88,99,5,10)'
'b=np.array(a).reshape(4,2)'
'print b'
This returns a 4-by-2 array of the desired numbers. Efficient? Or is there a better way. 
PS: I can't seem to get the hang of this mini-markdown formatting for the code lines. I apologise for that.

Comment: By initialize, I mean "set its initial values". What you did is fine.

Comment: @Petar: As far as the markdown goes, you really shouldn't be putting very much code in your comments anyway...nor asking very involved follow-up questions either.